# Find all matching elements with in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have an array of objects

I am searching within the array like this

```js
let arr = [
    { name:"string 1", arrayWithvalue:"1,2", other: "that" },
    { name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"2", other: "that" },
    { name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"2,3", other: "that" },
    { name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"4,5", other: "that" },
    { name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"4", other: "that" },
];
var item  = arr.find(item => item.arrayWithvalue === '4'); 
console.log(item)
```

This should return an array with this two rows

```
{ name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"4,5", other: "that" },
{ name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"4", other: "that" }
```

It returns only one row which is the first match.

```
{ name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"4", other: "that" }
```

I do not want to use any external libraries for this. How can I return all the matches that match the criteria?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Two things: first, `Array.find()` returns the first matching element, `undefined` if it finds nothing. `Array.filter` returns a new array containing all matching elements, `[]` if it matches nothing.

Second thing, if you want to match `4,5`, you have to look into the string instead of making a strict comparison. To make that happen we use `indexOf` which is returning the position of the matching string, or `-1` if it matches nothing.

---

**Example**:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'string 1',
    arrayWithvalue: '1,2',
    other: 'that',
  },
  {
    name: 'string 2',
    arrayWithvalue: '2',
    other: 'that',
  },
  {
    name: 'string 2',
    arrayWithvalue: '2,3',
    other: 'that',
  },
  {
    name: 'string 2',
    arrayWithvalue: '4,5',
    other: 'that',
  },
  {
    name: 'string 2',
    arrayWithvalue: '4',
    other: 'that',
  },
];

const items = arr.filter(item => item.arrayWithvalue.indexOf('4') !== -1);

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for,

Answer (score 10):

Use array filter method. 
Like

```
arr.filter(res => res.arrayWithvalue.indexOf('4') !== -1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `filter` method in place of `find`. This will return a new array containing just the members that return a truthy value from the passed in function.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.prototype.find()` will, as per the [MDN spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find): *return the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function*.

What you want to use instead is the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `.filter()` which will return an array of all instances that match your testing function.

Answer (score -3):

With [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) and [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/charAt).

```
const result = arr.filter(item => item.arrayWithvalue.charAt(0) === '4');
```

Comment: So know what happen if you wanna match 42 number? It's a bad advise to use `item.arrayWithvalue.charAt(0)`

Answer (score -3):

Use array.filter:

```js
var arr = [
    { name:"string 1", arrayWithvalue:"1,2", other: "that" },
    { name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"2", other: "that" },
{ name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"2,3", other: "that" },
{ name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"4,5", other: "that" },
{ name:"string 2", arrayWithvalue:"4", other: "that" },
];

var res = arr.filter(e => e.arrayWithvalue.split(',')[0] === '4');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: So know what happen if you wanna match `42` number? It's a bad advise to use `e.arrayWithvalue.split(',')[0]`